# System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am getting the below exception in a UserControl, Page Load. I have tried searching for this on Google, but have not found much information. Please let me know if anybody could help me with the same .

The situation is, there is one ascx.cs file for various usercontrols in different languages.

The application is running properly , but this exception is getting thrown for sometimes.

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at SmartSoft.SmartLiveWeb.UserControls.Common.PayoutForms.BoundAccountsOfMember()
at SmartSoft.SmartLiveWeb.UserControls.Common.PayoutForms.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Request information: 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: Forms 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\SLC Website

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                /*
                if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString["MId"] != null)
                    this.MId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get("MId"));
                */

                HideAllForms();
                AddValidationAttributesToControls();
                **BoundAccountsOfMember();**
                BoundWithdrawMethods();
                /*
                 * if (IsNetentConfirmationRequired())
                    LoadNetentConfirmationForm();
                 * 
                */
                CurrentPayoutMethod = (PayoutMethodEnum)Convert.ToInt16(SessionController.GetSessionData<object>("PayoutMethod"));
            }

            PlaceHolder phWithdraw = this.FindControl("phWithdraw") as PlaceHolder;
            Panel pnlKYC = this.FindControl("pnlKYC") as Panel;

            if (SessionController.CurrentMember != null && SessionController.CurrentMember.Approved == 10)
            {
                phWithdraw.Visible = false;
                pnlKYC.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                phWithdraw.Visible = true;
                pnlKYC.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Please find the BoundAccountsofMember  method code behind .

```
private void BoundAccountsOfMember()
        {
            Dictionary<Int16, AccountType> accountTypes = SessionController.CurrentMember.GetAccountTypes();

            ddlWithdrawFrom.Items.Clear();
            foreach (AccountType accountType in accountTypes.Values)
            {
                ddlWithdrawFrom.Items.Add(new ListItem(accountType.AccountName, accountType.AccountId.ToString()));
            }
            ListItem li = ddlWithdrawFrom.Items.FindByValue(SessionController.DefaultAccountId.ToString());
            if (li != null)
            {
                ddlWithdrawFrom.SelectedIndex = -1;
                li.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

The above exception is being thrown from Page_Load event.
Regards
Srividhya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could guess that you have a problem with a session here. You're checking `SessionController.CurrentMember != null` in `Page_Load`, but not in your `BoundAccountsOfMember`.

I believe that is a problem here if you're saying it happens time to time. You probably should work on session renewal/invalidation in your modules to make sure your code will not run without a valid session.